# How can i get the positive even elements in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to get all the even and positive elements in scheme

I have the following code

```
(define (getVals  lis)
  (cond
    ((null? lis) lis)
    (((> (car lis) 0) (even? (car lis)))
     (cons (getVals (cdr lis))))
    )
  )
```

To check my code im using

```
getVals '(2 -2 4 6 5))
```

Which should output a new list with positive and even numbers (2 4 6)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use built-in procedures:

```
(define (getVals lis)
  (filter (lambda (x) (and (even? x) (positive? x)))
          lis))
```

If you want to implement it from scratch, you need to fix your code:

- It's missing the case where the current element does *not* meet the conditions (the `else` case).
- It's missing one parameter when calling `cons`.
- The condition is missing an `and`.

This is what I mean:

```
(define (getVals lis)
  (cond
    ((null? lis) lis)
    ((and (even? (car lis)) (positive? (car lis)))
     (cons (car lis) (getVals (cdr lis))))
    (else (getVals (cdr lis)))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(getVals '(2 -2 4 6 5))
=> '(2 4 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

And just to add to @OscarLopez's answer - if you have a second look you will see, that `getVals` is just the specific case of `filter.

```
(define (getVals lis)
  (cond
    ((null? lis) lis)
    ((and (even? (car lis)) (positive? (car lis)))
     (cons (car lis) (getVals (cdr lis))))
    (else (getVals (cdr lis)))))
```

Versus:

```
(define (filter func lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lis) lst)
    ((func (car lst))
     (cons (car lst) (filter func (cdr lst))))
    (else (filter func (cdr lst)))))
```

With `filter func` as `getVales`, and
with `func` as:

```
(lambda (x) (and (even? x) (positive? x)))
```

`getVals` is just a special case of filter:

```
(define (getVals lst)
  (filter (lambda (x) (and (even? x) (positive? x))) lst))
```

But you should follow the style guide for Lisp languages -
don't use camelCase for function names but prefer the lisp-typic form `get-vals`.